# Why does Compare-And-Swap use Memory and Register

Tags: synchronization, locking, compare-and-swap

Why does the atomic swap instruction, which can be used to implement spin locks exchange data between a register and a memory location rather than swapping two registers’ contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is to change *the memory* atomically, you gain nothing by just swapping *registers* around because they only hold temporary data anyway.